# How can I write a Promise.all on a collection to quickly switch it from parallel to serial execution?

Tags: javascript

I find myself writing a lot of operations that process collections in parallel:

```
await Promise.all(someList.map(async (stuff) => {
  await process(stuff)
}))
```

This is excellent for production code, but when I want to debug some complex operations with logs, it really makes them hard to read, so while I'm debugging I'm often rewriting these operations to serial execution:

```
for (const stuff of someList) {
  await process(stuff)
}
```

This option destroys has much higher latency, and obviously is not suitable for production, but makes understanding what's going on much easier, especially when there are several such operations nested into each other.

What construct can I use to make switching from one way to another easier?

Comment: I don't think there's any simple solution to this.

Comment: You can write two helper functions `await mapConcurrent(someList, process)` and `await mapSequential(someList, process)` which can easily swapped out for each other. Possibly even using `const defaultMap = mapConcurrent` that you need to switch only in one location (like toggling a flag for "debug mode"). On the other hand, this will make heisenbugs much more likely.

Comment: Couldn't you put them both in an async function with an if statement and a flag variable?

Answer (score 0):

I use Bluebird.map

```
await Bluebird.map(
  someList,
  async (stuff) => process(stuff),
  { concurrency: isDev ? 1 : 10 },
})
```